# RabbitMQ/bunny: subscribe block not called if within a thread

Tags: ruby, multithreading, rabbitmq, bunny

I'm having trouble getting a queue subscribe block to execute if in a thread.

The example from [rubybunny/exchanges](http://rubybunny.info/articles/exchanges.html#topic_exchange_routing_example) works, as expected. However, if adapted with the consumer portion in a thread, the subscriber block appears not to execute.

I've tried several simple variations including setting a shared variable flag, all without success.

What am I missing?

Code

```ruby
#!/usr/bin/env ruby
require "bunny"

quit = false

consumer = Thread.new do
  puts "consumer start"

  cnx = Bunny.new
  cnx.start
  cn  = cnx.create_channel
  ex = cn.topic("weathr", :auto_delete => true)

  q = cn.queue("", :exclusive => true).bind(ex, :routing_key => "americas.north.#")
  q.subscribe do |delivery_info, properties, payload|
    puts "An update for North America: #{payload}, routing key is #{delivery_info.routing_key}"
  end

  loop {
    sleep 1
    break if quit
  }

  cnx.close
  puts "consumer done"
end

connection = Bunny.new
connection.start
connection  = connection.create_channel
exchange = connection.topic("weathr", :auto_delete => true)
exchange.publish("San Diego update", :routing_key => "americas.north.us.ca.sandiego").
  publish("Berkeley update",         :routing_key => "americas.north.us.ca.berkeley").
  publish("San Francisco update",    :routing_key => "americas.north.us.ca.sanfrancisco").
  publish("New York update",         :routing_key => "americas.north.us.ny.newyork").
  publish("São Paolo update",        :routing_key => "americas.south.brazil.saopaolo").
  publish("Hong Kong update",        :routing_key => "asia.southeast.hk.hongkong").
  publish("Kyoto update",            :routing_key => "asia.southeast.japan.kyoto").
  publish("Shanghai update",         :routing_key => "asia.southeast.prc.shanghai").
  publish("Rome update",             :routing_key => "europe.italy.roma").
  publish("Paris update",            :routing_key => "europe.france.paris")

sleep 5
connection.close

quit = true
consumer.join
```

Actual Output

```
consumer start
consumer done
```

Expected Output

```
consumer start
An update for North America: San Diego update, routing key is americas.north.us.ca.sandiego
An update for North America: Berkeley update, routing key is americas.north.us.ca.berkeley
An update for North America: San Francisco update, routing key is americas.north.us.ca.sanfrancisco
An update for North America: New York update, routing key is americas.north.us.ny.newyork
consumer done
```

Comment: As a note you can share connections between threads, but each thread does need its own channel.

Comment: Have you tried `subscribe(block: true, ...)` to get it to block while waiting for messages?

Comment: @tadman yes, I've tried `subscribe(:block => true)` but it doesn't seem to help get the block contents to executed.

Comment: I assume this is being done for test/proof of concept? Why wouldn't you just go ahead and start the thread up after you've done the queue declare, etc.?

Comment: @theMayer yes, this is just for poc and exploration.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The thread's subscribe block is not executing because the queue simply doesn't receive any messages. To elaborate, in this case, the queue ends up being created after the messages are published.

This can be visualized by switching the messages to `:mandatory => true` and using `Bunny::Exchange#on_return`:

Code

```ruby
#!/usr/bin/env ruby
require "bunny"

quit = false

connection = Bunny.new
connection.start

consumer = Thread.new do
  puts "consumer start"
  cn  = connection.create_channel
  ex = cn.topic("weathr", :auto_delete => true)

  q = cn.queue("", :exclusive => true).bind(ex, :routing_key => "americas.north.#")
  q.subscribe do |delivery_info, properties, payload|
    puts "An update for North America: #{payload}, routing key is #{delivery_info.routing_key}"
  end

  sleep 1 while !quit

  cn.close
  puts "consumer done"
end

channel = connection.create_channel
exchange = channel.topic("weathr", :auto_delete => true)
exchange.on_return do |basic_return, properties, payload|
  puts "#{payload} was returned! reply_code = #{basic_return.reply_code}, reply_text = #{basic_return.reply_text}"
end

exchange.publish("San Diego update", :mandatory => true, :routing_key => "americas.north.us.ca.sandiego").
  publish("Berkeley update",         :mandatory => true, :routing_key => "americas.north.us.ca.berkeley").
  publish("San Francisco update",    :mandatory => true, :routing_key => "americas.north.us.ca.sanfrancisco").
  publish("New York update",         :mandatory => true, :routing_key => "americas.north.us.ny.newyork").
  publish("São Paolo update",        :mandatory => true, :routing_key => "americas.south.brazil.saopaolo").
  publish("Hong Kong update",        :mandatory => true, :routing_key => "asia.southeast.hk.hongkong").
  publish("Kyoto update",            :mandatory => true, :routing_key => "asia.southeast.japan.kyoto").
  publish("Shanghai update",         :mandatory => true, :routing_key => "asia.southeast.prc.shanghai").
  publish("Rome update",             :mandatory => true, :routing_key => "europe.italy.roma").
  publish("Paris update",            :mandatory => true, :routing_key => "europe.france.paris")

channel.close
sleep 5

quit = true
consumer.join
connection.close
```

Output

```
consumer start
San Diego update was returned! reply_code = 312, reply_text = NO_ROUTE
Berkeley update was returned! reply_code = 312, reply_text = NO_ROUTE
San Francisco update was returned! reply_code = 312, reply_text = NO_ROUTE
New York update was returned! reply_code = 312, reply_text = NO_ROUTE
São Paolo update was returned! reply_code = 312, reply_text = NO_ROUTE
Hong Kong update was returned! reply_code = 312, reply_text = NO_ROUTE
Kyoto update was returned! reply_code = 312, reply_text = NO_ROUTE
Shanghai update was returned! reply_code = 312, reply_text = NO_ROUTE
Rome update was returned! reply_code = 312, reply_text = NO_ROUTE
Paris update was returned! reply_code = 312, reply_text = NO_ROUTE
consumer done
```

As we can see, all messages ended up getting returned with `NO_ROUTE`.

A simple solution to force the queue (and route) to exist before the messages are published:

```
#!/usr/bin/env ruby
require "bunny"

quit = false
consumer_queued = false

connection = Bunny.new
connection.start

consumer = Thread.new do
  puts "consumer start"
  cn  = connection.create_channel
  ex = cn.topic("weathr", :auto_delete => true)

  q = cn.queue("", :exclusive => true).bind(ex, :routing_key => "americas.north.#")
  consumer_queued = true
  q.subscribe do |delivery_info, properties, payload|
    puts "An update for North America: #{payload}, routing key is #{delivery_info.routing_key}"
    $stdout.flush
  end

  sleep 1 while !quit

  cn.close
  puts "consumer done"
end

# ensure queue is ready
sleep 0.125  while !consumer_queued

channel = connection.create_channel
exchange = channel.topic("weathr", :auto_delete => true)
exchange.on_return do |basic_return, properties, payload|
  puts "#{payload} was returned! reply_code = #{basic_return.reply_code}, reply_text = #{basic_return.reply_text}"
  $stdout.flush
end

exchange.publish("San Diego update", :mandatory => true, :routing_key => "americas.north.us.ca.sandiego").
  publish("Berkeley update",         :mandatory => true, :routing_key => "americas.north.us.ca.berkeley").
  publish("San Francisco update",    :mandatory => true, :routing_key => "americas.north.us.ca.sanfrancisco").
  publish("New York update",         :mandatory => true, :routing_key => "americas.north.us.ny.newyork").
  publish("São Paolo update",        :mandatory => true, :routing_key => "americas.south.brazil.saopaolo").
  publish("Hong Kong update",        :mandatory => true, :routing_key => "asia.southeast.hk.hongkong").
  publish("Kyoto update",            :mandatory => true, :routing_key => "asia.southeast.japan.kyoto").
  publish("Shanghai update",         :mandatory => true, :routing_key => "asia.southeast.prc.shanghai").
  publish("Rome update",             :mandatory => true, :routing_key => "europe.italy.roma").
  publish("Paris update",            :mandatory => true, :routing_key => "europe.france.paris")

channel.close
sleep 5

quit = true
consumer.join
connection.close
```

Output (with return notices)

```
consumer start
An update for North America: San Diego update, routing key is americas.north.us.ca.sandiego
São Paolo update was returned! reply_code = 312, reply_text = NO_ROUTE
An update for North America: Berkeley update, routing key is americas.north.us.ca.berkeley
Hong Kong update was returned! reply_code = 312, reply_text = NO_ROUTE
An update for North America: San Francisco update, routing key is americas.north.us.ca.sanfrancisco
Kyoto update was returned! reply_code = 312, reply_text = NO_ROUTE
An update for North America: New York update, routing key is americas.north.us.ny.newyork
Shanghai update was returned! reply_code = 312, reply_text = NO_ROUTE
Rome update was returned! reply_code = 312, reply_text = NO_ROUTE
Paris update was returned! reply_code = 312, reply_text = NO_ROUTE
consumer done
```

The expected messages are received and the rest are returned.